# gstreamer srtp for Full HD h.264 video

Tags: video, encryption, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, rtp

I am trying to implement a Full HD video conferencing solution on a Raspberry Pi 3. As I only need the the latency i just wanted to create one simple pipleline for audio and video.
I compiled gstreamer 1.13.0.1 from source, as the version 1.4.4 in the raspian repository is to old (had problems with G.722 encoding).
My pipline for encryption seems to work - but my pipline for decryption fails:
Encryption (runs):

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! \
  'video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! \
  h264parse config-interval=1 ! \
  rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1356955624' ! srtpenc key="012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ! udpsink host=10.0.0.132 port=5000
```

Decryption:
Decode:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! 'application/x-rtp,encoding-name=(string)H264,ssrc=(uint)1356955624,srtp-key=(buffer)012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789,srtp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm,srtp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80' ! srtpdec ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

> 0:00:00.234264235 26462  0x156b380 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE
>   grammar.y:726:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link udpsrc0 to
>   srtpdec0, srtpdec0 can't handle caps application/x-rtp,
>   encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)1356955624,
>   srtp-key=(buffer)012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789, srtp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80

So I think I need some additional caps - but which?

Comment: Try asking at the sister site [raspberrypi.se] for better answers :|

Comment: Thank's, I did. But I think this is not a very Raspberry Pi specific question. More a a GStreamer specific one.

Comment: Just changed application/x-rtp to application/x-srtp .... sometimes it can be that easy.. ;-)

Comment: I suggest that you post an answer to your own question -
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, but adding application/x-srtp was not enough to solve it for me. Using verbose output and debug warnings, I managed to trace it down to missing caps parameters. After looking here https://gstreamer-bugs.narkive.com/qAz9lMNM/bug-786304-new-srtpenc-srtpdec-don-t-work, I managed to get it working by adding `srtcp-cipher`, `srtcp-auth` and `roc` to caps:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! 'application/x-srtp, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1356955624, srtp-key=(buffer)012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789, srtp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80, srtcp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtcp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80, roc=(uint)0' ! srtpdec ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```